# Intersection form of logarithmic transformations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cohomology, 4-manifolds

Now I want to calculate the intersection form of a logarithmic transformation which is defined as follows.

Let $X$ be an oriented, closed, simply-connected 4-manifold and $T^2\subset X$
be an embedded 2-torus which has zero self intersection number.
Let $N(T^2)=T^2\times D^2$ denotes a closed tubular neighborhood in $X$.
Suppose that the complement of $T^2$ is simply-connected.
We consider an orientation preserving deffeomorphism $h$ of $T^2\times\partial D^2$
which satisfies the relation in **integral 1st homology** that $h_*[\partial D^2] = p[\alpha] + q[\beta] + r[\partial D^2]$,
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are standard basis loop of $T^2$.
Set $X(h):=(X-\text{int} N(T^2))\cup_h T^2\times D^2$. My question is:

> How can we calculate the intersection form of $X(h)$?

Just easy application of Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence? I couldn't get it by this approach. So I would like to get more detailed explanation. Thank you.

**EDIT1** : Yes, I already know that Euler characteristics and signatures of the two are same. So I really want to know the parity of intersection forms or spin structures. There is a reference ([*Six Lectures on Four 4-manifolds*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610700)) which says that:

- If $X$ is odd, then $X(h)$ is odd.
- If $r$ is odd and $X$ is even, then $X(h)$ is even.
- If $r$ and $X$ are even, then $X(h)$ is odd.

How can we prove that? **Any comments and answers are welcome!**

**EDIT2** : Here, $p,q$ and $r$ are an integer. Moreover, note that $\text{gcd}(p,q,r)=1$ holds because $[\partial D^2]$ is primitive in $H_1(T^2\times\partial D^2;\mathbb{Z})$.